# How to update all the changes from Datagrid to DB through TableAdapter.Update()

Tags: c#, datagrid, dataset, tableadapter

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, 32 bit version.

First of all, in my project, I created a **Server based Database**, and named it HR.mdf, so I am using LocalDB I guess, btw, I set its **Copy to Output dictionary** property to **Copy if newer**. In this database, I only have one simple table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[contractor] (
    [Id]        INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]      VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [IsMarried] BIT          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Secondly I created a **DataSet** item named HR, I dragged the contractor table into the design panel:

[image]

and VS 2015 generated three C# classes automatically: **HR**(it is a strongly typed DataSet, and has three inner classes, including a strongly typed DataTable **contractorDataTable**, ant so on.), **contractorTableAdapter** and **TableAdapterManager**.

So now my solution looks like:

[image]

Thirdly, I then dragged a Datagrid of contractor from **Data Sources** Tab into my WPF main window:

[image]

When running the program, the main window looks like:

[image]

And my C# code behind of MainWindow is:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace DataSetLab
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private DataSetLab.HR hR;
        private DataSetLab.HRTableAdapters.contractorTableAdapter hRcontractorTableAdapter;
        private System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource contractorViewSource;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            hR = ((DataSetLab.HR)(this.FindResource("hR")));
            // Load data into the table contractor. You can modify this code as needed.
            hRcontractorTableAdapter = new DataSetLab.HRTableAdapters.contractorTableAdapter();
            hRcontractorTableAdapter.Fill(hR.contractor);
            contractorViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("contractorViewSource")));
            contractorViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        }

        private void click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                hRcontractorTableAdapter.Update(hR.contractor);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                hRcontractorTableAdapter.Fill(hR.contractor);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I expected is when I click the submit button, all the changes I made in that grid are updated to the database, such editing a record and inserting a new record. But in fact, nothing happened after I clicked.

I found this tutorial from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171933(v=vs.140).aspx, but I didn't find Validate() or EndEdit() on any of the objects in MainWindow class.

I added a break point to Update() method in HR.design.cs, which is generated by VS 2015:

```
public partial class contractorTableAdapter : global::System.ComponentModel.Component {
    //...
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeywordAttribute("vs.data.TableAdapter")]
    public virtual int Update(HR.contractorDataTable dataTable) {
        return this.Adapter.Update(dataTable);
    }
    //...
}
```

But this point had never been reached.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance. Have googled quite a lot, not find anyone do it in this way.

Comment: This breakpoint will not be hit, because this method is marked with `DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute`. Place a break point on the `Update()` call in your click event instead. My suspicion is that your mdf is overwritten every time you run the project.

Comment: I know what you mean know, if I just run the generated .exe in /bin/debug, it saves the data to the copy of the .mdf under that path, and it seems to be overwritten by the copy under the root directory of the project.

Comment: According to MSDN, changing 'Copy to Output dictionary' to some options other than 'Copy always' should address this issue.

Comment: If you know it all, then what is you asking?

Answer (score 0):

@dotNet was right. The reason is the .mdf was overwritten, and my setting of 'Copy to Output dictionary' property didn't work because you need to restart Visual Studio 2015. I realized that this is not a good question in the end, and I feel sorry for that, I didn't find a way to close it, though, so I post an answer here.